# Are there any free apps or web sites for learning Hebrew?

Tags: resource-request, online-learning, hebrew

I am looking for an app or website for learning basic/beginner
 Hebrew. Since it's a less common language, Duolingo and other common programs do not have a Hebrew version. I'm looking for a free program with built in review and assessment.

This isn't a Google question. I have done many searches and not found any high quality programs that meets these simple criteria.

Comment: I just edited the title, as "best" is definitely going to be subjective, however, you may want to check out this post on meta: http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/190/why-was-are-there-books-or-resources-in-spanish-for-learning-latin-with-0-expe

Comment: As Hatchet mentioned, we can't answer what is the "best", because best is based on subjective criteria, thus primarily opinion based. I have edited your question to focus on the objective criteria you specified, so that we can hopefully help you find an answer.

Comment: What efforts have you made and what have you found so far (even if just by web searches)? Basic research should be included in your question. Are you saying you could not find any?

Comment: this question doesn't even require any expertise. Just go to google play store or the Apple Store

Comment: Duolingo has a 99% hatched course in Hebrew estimated to be in beta in early June. Can you wait a month?

Comment: @OldBunny2800: I'd make that an answer. Even if the OP doesn't consider it sufficient now, within 30 days it'll be perfectly valid :)

Comment: @user3169 see my edit

Comment: Can't help but mention that the Hebrew SE is also trying to work its way into existence, which could be a resource for somebody in the questioner's position. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102005/hebrew-language

Comment: WordReference has a [forum for the Hebrew language](http://forum.wordreference.com/forums/עברית-hebrew.43/), which may be helpful for beginners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Duolingo has a [fully hatched course in its incubator program](https://incubator.duolingo.com/courses/he/en/status), in which new languages are added to Duolingo. The course in Hebrew is now in public beta. Go on and give it a try!

Comment: Be aware that the percentages and estimated dates may be inaccurate due to unforeseen delays (for example, Russian was delayed by the absence of a quality text-to-speech program).

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the Hebrew version of **[Word Fireworks](http://wordfireworks.com/)**.  It costs $2 and available from the App Store, Google Play, and Amazon.  It's definitely a beginner app and probably best for picking up the writing system.  The app involves tracing Hebrew characters with your finger so you can communicate with aliens using pyrotechnics.

The app appears to be only available for languages that have writing systems very different from English (also Japanese, Chinese, and Korean).

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other resources mentioned here, I know of a [Beginner Hebrew app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.beginnerhebrew) and the [Hebrew Locker app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.hebrewlocker), both for Android.

Both apps work primarily on the basic Hebrew vocabulary and help you learn the commonly used Hebrew words and phrases from scratch and at your own pace.

Answer (score 1):

I just found [Free WordPower](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/learn-hebrew-free-wordpower/id293879908?mt=8) that seems similar to Duolingo. It has assessment built in.

Answer (score 1):

For learning the alphabet, I have found the Android app "Write it! Hebrew" by Jernung to be especially helpful. It allows you to trace the letters and you can set up your own custom tests (or ask to be tested on the entire alphabet). On the downside, it does not offer any assistance with Hebrew cursive, but learning the basic block forms is a huge step up in making it to cursive.

I have no affiliation with the app author.

Answer (score 1):

The best free Hebrew site that I have found and like to use is [Teach Me Hebrew](https://www.teachmehebrew.com/). In addition, [Learn Hebrew Pod](https://www.learnhebrewpod.com/speaking-hebrew/online-course) has many free lessons.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called [HelloTalk](https://www.hellotalk.com/) that I highly recommend. It works like a typical language exchange, so someone would work with you in Hebrew in exchange for you working with them in another language you know well.

Comment: Could you please reword your answer in more objective way and with more informative content. It currently reads too much like an advertisement.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Ok ,  I didn't meant to advertise it at all , sorry if it sounded like...