# Rigorous Hebrew course for an independent study?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, online-learning, hebrew

I'm a high-schooler looking to take an independent study course in Hebrew. My previous request was turned down due to not being rigorous enough (Ulpan-Or specifically). Can anyone recommend a decent, rigorous online course in Hebrew?

Edit: I am looking for a course in modern Hebrew

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange! Have you looked at https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/584/85 yet? I'm failing to see how this question is terribly different at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned. 'Free' is by no means a requirement for the selection, and in fact I imagine it would be pretty difficult to convince my counselor of the course's rigor if it were free. I'm not looking for a free app, I'm looking for a rigorous course with teachers.

Comment: Ok, sorry I missed that

Comment: Should the base language of the course be English or can it also be another language?

Comment: English is the only language in which I'm fluent

Comment: Could you [edit your question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/posts/3747/edit) to indicate the "period" of Hebrew you're interested in? I'm aware of two college-level courses in Biblical/Classical Hebrew (both from "Christian" sources, if that matters here), but it might be that you're after Israeli/Modern Hebrew.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what style of course you prefer, but the best and most in-depth podcast in Hebrew that I liked was [LearnHebrewPod](https://www.learnhebrewpod.com/speaking-hebrew/online-course). There is a ton of information there. Another great resource, though not really a traditional course, is [TeachMeHebrew](https://www.teachmehebrew.com/), which is a very unique site with great songs, lessons, and other useful information. As for other online course resources, [here](http://www.hebrew.ecott.ch/#On-line_courses) is a website that lists many, including my two favorites that I already highlighted.